# How could i recognize 2 separate key presses as one key?

Tags: c#

So for a game i'm working i have a bunch of different keys doing different things (for example w key makes the player look up and the e key makes the character look up right).

I'm wondering is there a way to make the W + the  D key make the player look up right, even though those keys are already being used.

```
private void FrmGM_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player1));
            bulletnumb = 1;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player2));
            bulletnumb = 2;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player3));
            bulletnumb = 3;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player4));
            bulletnumb = 4;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player5));
            bulletnumb = 5;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player6));
            bulletnumb = 6;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player7));
            bulletnumb = 7;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
        {
            picplayer.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.IPT_game_player8));
            bulletnumb = 8;
        }
```

this is the code for my keys presses

Comment: The answer is unclear. Usually YOU are the one coding what the keys should do. Showing us some code might help.

Answer (score 5):

Store letters in a set when the `KeyDown` events arrive, and remove them in the `KeyUp` event handler. This way your `KeyDown` would be able to "see" if the "companion key" has been pressed:

```
private readonly ISet<char> keysCurrentlyDown = new HashSet<char>();

private void FrmGM_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {            
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
    {
        if (keysCurrentlyDown.Contains('D')) {
            // Call some method to handle W+D
        } else {
            ...
        }
        keysCurrentlyDown.Add('W');
    } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    {
        if (keysCurrentlyDown.Contains('W')) {
            // Call some method to handle W+D
        } else {
            ...
        }
        keysCurrentlyDown.Add('D');
    }
    ...
}
private void FrmGM_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {            
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) {
        keysCurrentlyDown.Remove('W');
    } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) {
        keysCurrentlyDown.Remove('D');
    } ...
}

}
```

Comment: What is that `Set<T>` type you're using there? Note that by keeping the visual state management inside the keyboard input handling, you wind up duplicating effort (e.g. you have two different places you have to handle "Do something on W+D").

Comment: @PeterDuniho That's the `ISet<T>`, thanks. As far as handling W+D vs. D+W, I should have commented more carefully: whatever the action on W+D should be, the code should be placed in a method to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: You still wind up checking the W+D condition in two different places (albeit in different order each time), and of course while the implementation may be encapsulated in a single method, you still have to call it from two different places.  It would be better to simply check the state of the keyboard once all of the input has been processed, and just before the update for the current frame.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That's definitely true. My solution is for situations when you do not have a specific timeline, and the program must react when the second key press arrives. Your approach, on the other hand, is superior when you could do state checking on some schedule.

Comment: I think even when the visual state management is combined into the key-event handling, it would make sense to separate the operations: update the current key state, then update the visuals. One would have a method for each. Note that the second method would also be called from the key-up event handler, for a further consolidation/simplification of the code.

Answer (score 3):

The first line of offense for this sort of thing is just to make sure that each key can be activated concurrently, and that the combination of the effects of each key have the result you want. Your code will be more maintainable and easier to write if you follow that approach, rather than trying to special-case the combine key input.

For example, you can have a set of flags that represent the current key state, and then on your game's frame update, check those flags and set the character state to the correct thing (i.e. instead of setting specific images in the key-handling itself, as you're doing now).

So you could have flags like:

```
bool lookUp, lookRight, lookDown, lookLeft;
```

Then key-down for <kbd>W</kbd> would set the `lookUp` flag, while key-up for the same key would clear the flag. Likewise e.g. for <kbd>D</kbd>, for the `lookRight` flag.

Then on your game frame update, you check the flags. If `lookUp` and `lookRight` are both set, then you use the "look up and right" graphic. If just one or the other flag are set, then you use the plain "look up" or "look right" graphic. Likewise for other keys and their combinations. You could even resolve `lookUp` and `lookDown`, or `lookLeft` and `lookRight`, as whatever the default graphic would be (i.e. as if the user pressed no keys).

Note that if you're willing to use p/invoke, you can use the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function, and not even bother with the key-down event. Just check the key state before each frame update for the game, and update the visuals according to the current keyboard state. That way, you let Windows do all the key state tracking, and you don't waste time tracking key state that doesn't matter (e.g. if the user causes multiple changes to the key state between frames).

That said, if you can't/won't do any of the above, then yes...all you need to do is check for the combination first (i.e. you got the key-down for both, without a key-up for the initially-pressed key of the combination).

Do note that taking that approach means that you will still take the effect for the first key pressed, and then have to switch to the combination effect.

Answer (score 0):

use the

**PresentationCore.dll** and the 
**WindowsBase.dll** as reference in your project

PresentationCore.dll has a Keyboard - Class and WindowsBase.dll has a Key - Class.

then:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Windows.Input;

            namespace ViewTest
            {
                public partial class ViewTest : Form
                {
                    private void ViewTest_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.W) && 
                            Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.D))
                        {
                            // do something
                        }
                    }
            }
```

it's a simple way to do this :)

Comment: So on _every_ key-down event, you are suggesting the OP check _every_ possible key combination? Uh...that seems somewhat non-optimal, to say the least.

Comment: that's what he's doing now too

Comment: Yes, but his code could be converted to a `switch` (and should be), and thus would be more efficient. The above can't be. Note also that there's no indication in the OP that he's using WPF. In fact, it looks very much like Winforms. Dragging in the WPF DLLs just for key state handling is also not very efficient.

Answer (score -2):

Look into overriding the `ProcessCmdKey`

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys k)
{
    if (k == (Keys.Control | Keys.D))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CTRL+D");

        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, k);
}
```